# How to manage Google Webmaster Tools for Multiple Clients

Tags: google-search-console

I need to set up Google Webmaster Tools for several of my clients. Is it alright to add multiple sites under my own Google account and then add clients as other owners if they need access? If further down the line my clients decide they want control would setting it up like this cause problems?

Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Comment: More info on managing multiple users in GWT: https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44227

Answer (score 2):

I usually create free outlook.com or gmail.com adresses like this:

```
client.projectname@email.com
client.otherproject@email.com
```

Whenever they want to remove me completely, I simply hand over the account and they may change the passwords themselves.

Comment: Yeah, at that time it just seems easier to just go ahead and set everything up for the client. If the client wants to switch companies or likes to manage the accounts themselves it's just an easier explanation to just hand over everything instead of explaining the customer why this and that doesn't work or why he needs to setup a completely new account.

Comment: But there's a limit on accounts number managed from the same IP Address and phone number. How do you overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

I have gained access to client sites under my own Google account and then unverified myself when my relationship with the client ended.  It doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: Just to add... when you add another owner to a site, the other verified owners on that site get notified. And any site owner can unverify any other site owner - or you unverify yourself as Stephen suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely run into problems later down the line when they want to remove your access, since it'll be registered on your account you are the master and therefore unremovable. It's best to gain access to their account or ask them to add you as an administrator. That way they can simply remove you without the need of having to ask you to remove the domain and then having them verify it.

Personally I ask for their login details to gmail since asking them to find the add administrator and so forth can be tasking if they ain't very good with computers.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, better to set up like this from start to avoid problems later. I'll see how they get on adding me as a user. Not comfortable asking for their gmail login.

Comment: @user21364: Maybe set up a gmail/google account specifically for this purpose? I can't imagine anyone being happy about giving out details of a "personal" account?

Comment: @w3d Thanks. Yes, next time will set up specific gmail to avoid having to explain to owner how to set up GWT and add me as user.

Comment: Just to note... the developer/owner is only _unremovable_ if the client was added as a "delegated" user from the developers account. If the client is added as another _owner_ (ie. you go through the process of verification on the clients account) then you have 2 owners. Any "owner" can unverify any other owner.